# У меня не запускается скомпилированный в exe проект WinForms

Tags: c#

Написал маленькую программу, которая состоит из 2 проектов, WinForms и логики. Для компиляции использовал расширение Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022. В папку добавил выходной элемент 2 проектов и установил его. Но запуская exe-файл, ничего не происходит. Смотрел разные решения проблем, но не помогло. Как можно правильно скомпилировать программу, чтобы она запускалась?

Comment: https://github.com/Zimmerman23/Glossa вот ссылка на это чудо

Comment: VS 2022 умеет собирать проекты безо всяких расширений. О чём речь? Журналы Windows смотрите, там информация о сбоях в приложении может быть. Версия дотнета хотя-бы какая?

Answer (score 2):

"Для компиляции использовал расширение Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022" - последнее не имеет никакого отношения к компиляции. Ваш проект компилируется Visual Studio, а то, что упомянуто, предназначено для создания дистрибутива.

Итак, требуемая последовательность действий:

1. Скомпилировать проект в Visual Studio - компиляция должна пройти без ошибок.
2. Запустить проект из-под Visual Studio - он должен работать.
3. С помощью Installer создать дистрибутив - операция должна пройти без ошибок.
4. Перенести дистрибутив на другой компьютер и установить там приложение.
5. Запустить приложение.

И где у вас происходит сбой? Из ваших объяснений не очень понятно.